# Unable to get gradle.properties when running bootRun through Docker

Tags: spring-boot, docker, gradle, gradle.properties, bootrun

I am trying to use a local gradle.properties file in gradle.build for my spring boot application. When running bootrun from gradle.properties, the application works as it should, but when running bootRun from a docker file i get this error:

```
#11 17.91 * Where:
#11 17.91 Build file '/home/gradle/src/build.gradle' line: 93
#11 17.91
#11 17.91 * What went wrong:
#11 17.91 A problem occurred evaluating root project 'project_name'.
#11 17.91 > Could not get unknown property 'filePath' for task ':properties' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.diagnostics.PropertyReportTask.
```

I think this may be due to docker not being able to access gradle.properties file. Does anybody have a tip on how to fix this? Thx in advance